# Python module for managing dns and dhcp

Tags: python, django, dns, dhcp

I'm writing an application in django that will be creating/destroying dns (bind) and dhcp (dhcpd) records on a RHEL server. I was wondering if there is a module/modules in python that allow me to do that without to need to worry about editing the config files myself?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try the dns.zone.Zone class from dnspython for zone files:
http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.10.0/html/dns.zone-module.html#from_file

It may be that the Roster DNS management has an API that you could use.
http://code.google.com/p/roster-dns-management/